# Помогите записать код одной строкой используя генератор списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Подскажите, как данный код:

```
production_year_x, production_year_y = 2014, 2015
rus_name_x, rus_name_y = 'Terminator 1', 'Terminator 2'

if production_year_x is not None:
    main_x = rus_name_x + ' | ' + str(production_year_x)
else:
    main_x = rus_name_x + ' | '

if production_year_y is not None:
    compare_y = {site_y: rus_name_y + ' | ' + str(production_year_y)}
else:
    compare_y = {site_y: rus_name_y + ' | '}
```

записать одной строкой через генератор списков (list comprehension)?

Получилось написать такой код, но не могу его довести до ума:

```
main_x, compare_y,a,b = [name + ' | ' + str(year) for name in [rus_name_x, rus_name_y] for year in [production_year_x, production_year_y]]
```

В данном случае нужно получить результат:

1. main_x = 'Terminator 1 | 2014'
2. compare_y = 'Terminator 2 | 2015'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывел списки в отдельные переменные, так как если этого не сделать, генератор списка сильно длинный получается.

```
production_year_x, production_year_y = 2014, 2015
rus_name_x, rus_name_y = 'Terminator 1', 'Terminator 2'    
#
names = [rus_name_x, rus_name_y]
years = [production_year_x, production_year_y]
main_x, compare_y = [names[years.index(year)] + ' | ' + str(year) if year is not None else names[years.index(year)] + ' | ' for year in years]
print(main_x, '\n', compare_y)
Terminator 1 | 2014
Terminator 2 | 2015

production_year_x, production_year_y = 2014, None
Terminator 1 | 2014
Terminator 2 |
production_year_x, production_year_y = None, 2015
Terminator 1 |
Terminator 2 | 2015
production_year_x, production_year_y = None, None
Terminator 1 |
Terminator 2 |
```

"Традиционный" вид генератора:

```
for name in [rus_name_x, rus_name_y]:
    i = [rus_name_x, rus_name_y].index(name)
    year = [production_year_x, production_year_y][i]
    if year is not None:
        x = name + '|' + str(year)
    else:
        x = name + '|'
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно хотелось чего-нибудь этакого:

```
x, y = [" | ".join(i) for i in zip(["T_1", "T_2"], map(str, (d or "" for d in [2014, 2015])))]
```

Но ведь простое лучше сложного...

Comment: Конечно хотелось бы по-проще... В вашем случае есть проблемка - если вместо года поставить None, то ответ будет ('T_1 | 2014', 'T_2 | None'), а нужно ('T_1 | 2014', 'T_2 | '). В коде в шапке это описывается в "ветке" "else"